# windows phone 7 open an application on a specific time

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am building an wake up light alarm for windows phone 7, but before the alarm shows up, I have to change the background, to imitate a sunrise.

So when the user defines his alarm and exits the application, the application needs to start up 30 minutes before the alarm, to change the background.

Is it possible to open an application(Page) on a specific time?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to launch an application at a specified time.
You can schedule an alarm or a reminder, but they are handled by the OS. Also, the alarms or reminders that your application registers can't provide a mechanism that allows the user to open the application directly from the alarm (o reminder).

you can refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202965%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) documentation entry.